# Resolving IP address to get Domain Name

Tags: dns

How to make my server be resolved by IP address and get the domain name. For example: then Anyone can use:

```
resolveip <my-ip>
```

And get the output of my domain name; like www.xyz.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For IPv4

If your IP address is `a.b.c.d`, then you need to add the following DNS entry:

```
d.c.b.a.IN-ADDR.ARPA    IN    PTR    your-domain.name.
```

This entry needs to be added to the authoritative name server that hosts the zone in which it is located. That server is usually run by your service provider.

### For IPv6

If your IP address is `abcd:9efg:hijk:lmno:pqrs:tuvw:xyz0:1234`, then you need to add the following DNS entry:

```
4.3.2.1.0.z.y.x.w.v.u.t.s.r.q.p.o.n.m.l.k.j.i.h.g.f.e.9.d.c.b.a.IP6.ARPA    IN    PTR    your-domain.name.
```

Again, in the appropriate zone file.

Comment: I must follow this rule d.c.b.a.IN-ADDR.ARPA or can I put what I want and it will be work?

Comment: You must follow that pattern. That's the exact DNS entry that clients will look up when attempting to resolve IPv4 address `a.b.c.d` to a name. Generally, this means that the `c.b.a.IN-ADDR.ARPA` zone or some higher zone must already have been delegated to you by a higher authority.

Answer (score 3):

Contact the administrator of your ip-range and ask them to set up the PTR or reverse DNS record for your ip-address to your desired server name. If you have a range assigned by your provider they may offer the option to delegate reverse DNS of your ip-range to your DNS servers

Typically most VPS and server providers have a provision for that in their control panel allowing their customers to do that themselves.

Comment: Ahmm. I am the admin of IP range. I will try to put that record in my server. Tnx.

Comment: If it is private range no problem doing it in your own DNS. If it is a public range you own (and it's not a range your ISP provides for you) the RIPE procedure or similar is probably what you need if you want the general public to be able use the reverse DNS: http://www.ripe.net/data-tools/dns/reverse-dns/how-to-set-up-reverse-delegation

Comment: Tnx for the answer